# Gradient light from center in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

It's not hard to make gradient lighting like this using Photoshop:

[image]

But I want to make the lighter part as a point in the center, with gradient along radials.

How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before drawing the gradient with the gradient tool, click any of the gradient modes on top of the screen in the options bar:

[image: gradient options bar]

The one circled is the one you want for a radial gradient.

In case you don't have the options bar visible, you can activate it in the 'Window' menu by clicking 'Options'.

If you're drawing your gradient using a gradient overlay layer style, you'll want to search out the 'Style' option in the layer style dialog box. Choose 'radial' there for the effect you're looking for!

Comment: But how do you CENTER it? Having to eyeball it is lame. It's weird that Photoshop doesn't have a Fill/Gradient option, which would by default of course center itself in the selection/on active layer. Very strange.